# how to connect mongodb with replicaset url?

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-virtual-machine, bitnami, azure-virtual-network

I'm using MongoDB with replication(bitnami) on Azure. 
I have created three mongodb nodes(1 primary ,1 secondary and 1 arbiter).
When I try to connect with MongoDB connection URI `(mongodb://username:password@ip01:27017,ip02:27017,ip03:27017/?readPreference=primary&replicaSet=replicaset)`  it gives me error like `pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: 10.0.0.5:27017: timed out,10.0.0.6:27017: [Errno 113] No route to host,10.0.0.4:27017: timed out,10.0.0.7:27017: timed out` 
I prefered this [Official Documentation (Bitnami)](https://docs.bitnami.com/azure-templates/infrastructure/mongodb/) for connection url.

```
connectionString = "mongodb://root:Root123@*.*.*.*:27017,*.*.*.*:27017,*.*.*.*:27017/?replicaSet=replicaset"
client= MongoClient(connectionString)
db = client['mongo_collection']
data = db.xyz.find({"x": 10})
for d in data:
    print d
```

Comment: Considering that `10.x.x.x` is actually a "private" IP range, then I would suggest actually need to supply the "public" addresses for each node for something outside of the net to reach it. Either that or you need to set up routing rules that allow access from the client node to each of those instances. Seems like a question for [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com) or perhaps Azure support. But not a programming question, which is what StackOverflow is for.

Comment: @NeilLunn I'm supplying DNS name in connection URL and I think DNS name is accessible from outside.

Comment: DNS Names really don't make a difference in so far  as which IP Address they actually resolve to. As stated, this is a "networking issue" and not a "programming issue".  There is an appropriate site to ask questions about networking configuration. That is what "host unreachable" means. So it's not the code, but the network accessibility.

Comment: Ok Thank you @NeilLunn i ll ask this question  serverfault.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [official document](https://docs.bitnami.com/azure-templates/infrastructure/mongodb/) which you provided.

> Ensure that the application is able to connect to each cluster node
>   using its public or private IP address. To ensure connectivity, you
>   have two options:
>
> Host the application in the same network as the MongoDB cluster so
>   that it can address each node using its private IP address. This is
>   the recommended configuration for production environments. Host the
>   application in a different network and assign public IP addresses,
>   with appropriate firewall rules, to the cluster nodes (if not already
>   assigned by default) so that the application can address each node
>   using its public IP address. This configuration is not recommended for
>   production environments.

So, if you test in the same Azure Virtual Network, you could use private IP(example 10.0.0.6). I test in my lab, I use python with this [example](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver?jmp=docs).

```
import pymongo
client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://root:<passsword>@10.0.0.6:27017,10.0.0.4:27017,10.0.0.5:27017/?replicaSet=replicaset")

db = client.test
>>> db.name
u'test'
>>> db.my_collection
Collection(Database(MongoClient(host=['10.0.0.5:27017', '10.0.0.6:27017', '10.0.0.4:27017'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True, replicaset='replicaset'), u'test'), u'my_collection')
>>> db.my_collection.insert_one({"x": 10}).inserted_id
ObjectId('5987cc0b9e90d52dd1860ac3')
```

Update:

If you want to connect your mongodb nodes, you should need ping the private IP. It is a design behavior.

If you want to mongodb from your app or local, you need create a Site-to-Site VPN connection or Point-to-Site VPN connection.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, if your client is not in Azure Vnet, you need create a VPN connection or use Public IP to connect mongodb. I update my answer, you could check.

Comment: @Tailor Devendra Hi, if possible, could you share your result? Do you solve this issue?

Comment: Hi, does it work, if you have any question about this, I am very happy very to solve it.

Comment: Hi, @walter-MSFT, I have already done what you have suggested above but I am getting the same error what I have mentioned in my question, in addition to error message my replica set nodes are not reachable. do you think that it has something to do with replica set configuration?

Comment: @TailorDevendra No, this is a network issue? What you test it ? On your db node VM or your local? When you test, you should ensure you could `telnet ip 27017`.

Comment: @TailorDevendra The root reason is you could not access the service. When you use telnet to test, you will get timeout error. I am sure.

Comment: @TailorDevendra On your db node VM, do the command `netstat -ant|grep 27017`. Please ensure the port is listening on all node.

Comment: @TailorDevendra Hi, I test in my lab many times, it all works for me. I suggest you could `telnet` to test you could access the service and use API to access db.

Comment: I tried all above solutions. telnet is working fine and the port is listening on all nodes.

Comment: I meet the same error log with you. When I test on db nodes, it works, but when I test on other VM, it fails.

Comment: @TailorDevendra On your test environment, you should ping 10.0.0.4/5/6. Maybe you need create a site-to-site VPN.

Comment: @TailorDevendra  It is a design behavior. You could not get mongodb with Public IP address. Please refer to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45519064/how-to-connect-mongodb-with-replicaset-url). Mongodb driver does not support this.

Comment: @TailorDevendra When I test in mogodb nodes, your script works for me. But when I test outside the VNet, it does not work. Do you meet the same result?

Comment: Bitnami Developer here. If you want to use the database from outside the VNet, then, as @walter-msft says, you should create a VPN.

Comment: @TailorDevendra As Javier said, you need create a VPN, you could create a [point-to-site VPN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-resource-manager-portal) or [site-to-site VPN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-site-to-site-resource-manager-portal).

Comment: Thank you @Walter-MSFT and Javier Salmeron. It worked

Comment: I managed to get my App Service Plan (Resource Group) connected to a Bitnami Replica Set (another Resource Group) by using virtual network peering. This is the best option imho.